# How does freelance job operate?

Tags: freelancing

I want to find a freelance job, but I've never done any freelance work before. I want to know what the process involves. Can you please answer the following questions?

1. If the programmer finds a suitable freelance job, how can they apply, and how will the future employer evaluate the programmer's abilities?
2. How does the programmer deliver their work?
3. How does the programmer receive money? What if the employer and the employee are in different countries? How do they pay?
4. Do you really read the agreement when signing an account on a freelance website?
5. Any pitfalls? Under what circumstances will the employer not pay after the work is done?

Comment: The TOS agreements for the accounts on freelance websites are usually harmless. But what you should definitely read carefully are the contracts with the clients themself. Many try to screw you over with liability or quality assurance clauses which are simply impossible to fulfill.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1)programmer found a suitable
>   freelance job, how can he apply, and
>   how to future employer evaluate the
>   programmer's ability?

Web sites like rent-a-coder, personal recomendations, recruitment agencies, advertising your services, being prominent on websites/forums/blogs for a particular technology.

> 2)how do programmer deliver their
>   work?

Typically over the inter-web-tubes, but you could post a CD. I've even delivered entire machines.

> 3)how do programmer receive the money?
>   What if the employer and the employee
>   come from difference country? How do
>   they pay?

Paypal, bank draft, cheque/check, wire transfer. That's usually the simplest part of the process!

> 4)Do you really read the agreement
>   when signing an account on a freelance
>   website?

Probably not - if the third party is going to screw you they are going to screw you. The only question is if they do it the cheap way by keeping your money or the expensive way with lawyers.

> 5)Any pitfall of freelance?

Not getting any work, only getting work when you are too busy. Customers changing their mind half way through, customers changing their mind when you deliver, having to deal with tax, insurance, pension, etc yourself.

> 5b) Under what circumstances will the
>   employer not paying after the work is
>   done?

When they think they can get away with it.
When they don't want the code anymore because their needs have changed, when they don't need the code because they never did but have only just realised.
When the customer goes bust or dissapears before,during or after you deliver...

Comment: A subject like this can fill a book (actually, it can and has filled many books) but this answer provides a concise high-level overview.

Comment: Oh, please help for the updated questions.

Comment: re "Under what circumstances will the employer not paying after the work is done", this is what I like about vWorker (used to be known as RentaCoder) -- all money is put into escrow before the project is started, and if you deliver on time, the client is obligated to pay.